# Adding Application Mapings to an IIS6 website on Windows XP

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-xp

I am trying to add an Application Extension Mapping to a website in IIS6 running on windows XP. My steps are as follows:

Home directory > Configuration > Mappings > Add

```
Executable: aspnet_isapi.dll
Extension: .xml
Verbs: All Verbs
```

but the OK button is always greyed out.

Is this a limitation of IIS6 on XP?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set it to:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
```

(or, copy the path from .aspx - you can't use ctrl commands, right click the text box instead)

Additionally, you should deselect 'Check that file exists'